# All subsets of a list in Perl 6

Tags: math, set, raku

I wonder (remembering that Perl 6 has everything you could wish), whether there are some built-in instruments that can help to produce all the non-empty subsets (order doesn't matter) of a list.

E.g., I have a list:

```perl6
my @a = 1, 2, 3;
```

I need a function `f` so that `f(@a)` will produce:

```perl6
((1), (2), (3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
@a.combinations(1..*)
```

will return the `Seq` you're looking for. Note that without the argument, an empty list would be generated as first element.

Comment: Wow! Perl 6 can do everything!